# SP2013 Windows Auth Default Domain

Tags: authentication, windows-authentication, domain

We have "outsiders" who happen to have users in our domain but, when login in, since they are inside their own domains, they have to remove their domain (THEIR_DOMAIN\USER) and set ours (OUR_DOMAIN\USER).

Since most of them are reluctant to do so or don't know how to, even tough we released a few User Manuals detailing how to proceed...

Is there a way to set a **default domain** for a Windows Auth WebApp in SP2013?

Seen a few posts regarding custom login, wouldn't like it to come to that, but I could get my bosses head around if that's the only choice we have.

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, this is a client-side browser behavior, not something that can be controlled from your server(s).  If the user performs the action once and chooses the "remember these credentials" setting, then it will use the correct credentials next time -- unfortunately, there is no option to just "remember username", without also remembering the password.

As you suggest, only a custom forms-based login will allow you to control what domain the users can type or select.  If you only even have the one domain, you could even make that form ignore whatever comes before the "\" (slash) or after the "@" (at sign), and just use the supplied username/password on your known internal domain.  But it seems a bit extreme to build a custom form-based login just because some users don't understand their domain prefix.